# Hierarchical Dictionary in Python

Tags: pandas

I want to create a hierarchy like the one in the image but with three levels. The uniqe values of the third level are set by the business below. How should i define the region dictionary? The business level takes three uniqu values that are nested within the region values.

Thanks in advance!

```py
states = df["state"].unique()

regions = df["state_region"].unique()

business=df["state_region_business"].unique()

total = {'total': list(states)}

state = {k: [v for v in regions if v.startswith(k)] for k in states}

region=?
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```py
import difflib

# == Define Some Dummy Data ===================================================
regions = [
    "SA_Adelaide",
    "SA_Adelaide_Hills",
    "SA_Barossa",
    "SA_Clare_valley",
    "SA_Eyre_Peninsula",
    "SA_Fleurieu_Peninsula",
    "SA_Flinders_Ranges_and_Outback",
    "SA_Kangoroo_Island",
    "SA_Limestone_Coast",
    "SA_Riverland",
    "SA_Yorke_Peninsula",
]

states = ["SA", "NT", "WA", "VIC", "NSW", "QLD", "ACT"]
business = [
    "SA_Adelaide_A",
    "SA_Adelaide_B",
    "SA_Adelaide_C",
    "SA_Adelaide_D",
    "SA_Adelaide_E",
    "SA_Adelaide_F",
    "SA_Adelaide_Hills_XY",
    "SA_Barossa_ABC",
    "SA_Barossa_DEF",
    "SA_Eyre_Peninsula_E",
    "SA_Flinders_Ranges_and_Outback_AUS",
    "SA_Kangoroo_Island_ZOO",
]

# == Define Hierarchical Dict ==================================================
hierarchical_dict = {
    "total": states,
    "states": {
        state: {
            region: [
                b
                for b in business
                if difflib.get_close_matches(b, regions, n=1)[0] == region
            ]
            for region in regions
            if region.startswith(state)
        }
        for state in states
    },
}
hierarchical_dict
# Returns:
#
# {
#     "total": ["SA", "NT", "WA", "VIC", "NSW", "QLD", "ACT"],
#     "states": {
#         "SA": {
#             "SA_Adelaide": [
#                 "SA_Adelaide_A",
#                 "SA_Adelaide_B",
#                 "SA_Adelaide_C",
#                 "SA_Adelaide_D",
#                 "SA_Adelaide_E",
#                 "SA_Adelaide_F",
#             ],
#             "SA_Adelaide_Hills": ["SA_Adelaide_Hills_XY"],
#             "SA_Barossa": ["SA_Barossa_ABC", "SA_Barossa_DEF"],
#             "SA_Clare_valley": [],
#             "SA_Eyre_Peninsula": ["SA_Eyre_Peninsula_E"],
#             "SA_Fleurieu_Peninsula": [],
#             "SA_Flinders_Ranges_and_Outback": [
#                 "SA_Flinders_Ranges_and_Outback_AUS"
#             ],
#             "SA_Kangoroo_Island": ["SA_Kangoroo_Island_ZOO"],
#             "SA_Limestone_Coast": [],
#             "SA_Riverland": [],
#             "SA_Yorke_Peninsula": [],
#         },
#         "NT": {},
#         "WA": {},
#         "VIC": {},
#         "NSW": {},
#         "QLD": {},
#         "ACT": {},
#     },
# }
```

**Looking at a single region output:**

```py
print(hierarchical_dict['states']['SA']['SA_Adelaide'])
# Prints:
#
# ['SA_Adelaide_A', 'SA_Adelaide_B', 'SA_Adelaide_C', 'SA_Adelaide_D', 'SA_Adelaide_E', 'SA_Adelaide_F']
```

### Notes

I've used the `difflib` module because some of your regions have very similar names. If you use something like `[b for b in business if b.startswith(region)]` you would have businesses like `"SA_Adelaide_Hills_XY"` being included inside `"SA_Adelaide"` region:

```py
hierarchical_dict = {
    "total": states,
    "states": {
        state: {
            region: [b for b in business if b.startswith(region)]
            for region in regions
            if region.startswith(state)
        }
        for state in states
    },
}
print(hierarchical_dict['states']['SA']['SA_Adelaide'])
# Prints:
#
# [
#     "SA_Adelaide_A",
#     "SA_Adelaide_B",
#     "SA_Adelaide_C",
#     "SA_Adelaide_D",
#     "SA_Adelaide_E",
#     "SA_Adelaide_F",
#     "SA_Adelaide_Hills_XY",  # <-- WRONG REGION!
# ]
```

#### `difflib` vs. `str.startswith`

Here's another example of the difference between both approaches:

**`difflib.get_close_matches`:**

```py
difflib.get_close_matches(
    "SA_Adelaide_Hills_XY",
    ["SA_Adelaide_Hills", "SA_Adelaide", "SA_Adelaide_Hill"],
    n=1,
)
# Returns:
# ['SA_Adelaide_Hills']
```

**`str.startswith`:**

```py
[
    region
    for region in ["SA_Adelaide_Hills", "SA_Adelaide", "SA_Adelaide_Hill"]
    if "SA_Adelaide_Hills_XY".startswith(region)
]
# Returns:
# ['SA_Adelaide_Hills', 'SA_Adelaide', 'SA_Adelaide_Hill']
```